# Correlations between two questionnaires that have different scoring scale

Tags: correlation

For example, questionnaire 1 has 20 items scored from 1-5, questionnaire 2 have 10 items, and it is a True/False scale (so the final score is like true =1, false =0, and add them up), can I still do a Pearson correlation between them? If I had to standardize the score, how should I standardize them? just merely averaging everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact some of your items contain different ranges of numeric values (i.e., [1,5] for 18 of your items & [0,1] for your two T/F items) is not problematic. For example, in past work, I would often estimate the correlation between salary and years of experience, which do not have the same range (e.g., [0-50] for years of experience and [30,000, 750,000] for salary). The issue is that your items are categorical. Specifically, your T/F items are dichotomous, and your other 18 items are ordinal. [Pearson's correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) is a measure of linear association between two continuous variables. As the number of response options goes to infinity, this will typically be less problematic; however, because two of your items are dichotomous, I would suggest you consider alternative measures of linear association. Given this, the [spearman's rank correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) and/or [tetrachoric/polychoric correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation) may be viable alternatives.

Comment: Got it!! Thank you so much! :D

Comment: No problem @IvesDragonfly! If you found my answer helpful, please accept my answer and give it an upvote!